# Autofill some words in a text field when a particular image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I know how to make a text field in HTML. But what i want is this: I have a text field, and five images below it. If a user clicks first image, the word "p1" should be automatically written in the text field. If the user clicks the second image, the word "p2" should be written and so on uptil "p5". The user is free to click any image any number of times. He can also type using his keyboard and alternately click on the images.
So how do I make this autofilling of "p1", "p2", etc. happen when the user clicks an image?

EDIT:
Suppose the first image is:

`<img src="image1.jpg" alt="p1" onclick="write('p1')">`

So what should be written in the body of the function write() to achieve the task?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code factory. Please update your question with the specific programming problem you need help with.

Comment: try $("#yourtextfieldid").val('p1 or something') when onclick

Comment: @Dinesh he/she made no mention of jQuery

Comment: You've already somewhat answered this question yourself... you included the "onclick" tag.  That's the answer.  Take a stab at the code after reading about how to use onclick and update your question with a specific problem you've ran into when attempting to implement the solution.

Comment: @Matt Sorry buddy, I think jquery is a javascript library so only i say.

Comment: @whaley can u help me now? i have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function write(text){
    document.getElementById("textFieldId").value += text;
}
```

Comment: @DavidPärsson if you mean `document.getElementById("textFieldId").value += text;`
This would add the value of the image on to the end of the text field, rather than replacing it. 
Both work but I'm not too sure which one muzzz needs.

Comment: That's at least how i interpret the question.